# Maintaining Aspect Ratio Using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

Is there any way to tell ffmpeg to preserve the aspect ratio when resizing a video by adding padding in the shorter dimension?  I know that I can do it by manually adding the proper amount of padding, but I am converting many videos of arbitrary sizes, and I cannot do each one manually.  I read somewhere that the -s option used to do this, but it does not any more.  To clarify, I am not looking to fix the height and let the width be whatever it needs to be to preserve the ratio (as I have seen in other questions).

Comment: By "adding padding", you mean pillar- or letterboxing?

Comment: @slhck: Yes, I do.

Comment: Do you want a fixed width?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: I want to fix the width _and_ the height but have it pillar- or letterboxed to preserve the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to preserve the aspect ratio when resizing a video by adding
>   padding in the shorter dimension?

```
ffmpeg -i 01.jpg -vf scale=-1:360,pad=640:ih:(ow-iw)/2 -qmax 1 360-01.jpg
```

I havent used this command in a while so YMMV.

[FFmpeg slideshow](http://svnpenn.github.io/2012/05/ffmpeg-slideshow)